# Goldbach's problem in algebraic number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics, circle-method

Are there any results on the representation of numbers in algebraic number fields as the sum of primes in the ring of integers in that field? There are some results for Waring's problem  in other fields, like [this paper by Siegel](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2371900?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), but I haven't found anything of the sort for representing numbers as the sum of primes.

Comment: The fact that a prime times a unit is a prime is significant and might make some formulations of the problem easier.

Comment: I always find it amusing when duplicate questions have more upvotes than the original.  I will upvote the original to try to remedy this.

Comment: To spell out Will's point a little more, should "under the following conditions, $a$ is of the form $\pi_1+\pi_2$ for $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ prime" be viewed as a generalization of the Goldbach conjecture, or a generalization of the twin prime conjecture?